# Chrome suggests/predicts search results in the omnibox while incognito

Tags: google-chrome, search

I've recently noticed that Chrome will sometimes predict and offer autocomplete suggestions for **search results** (as opposed to previously visited sites or bookmarked sites) in the omnibox while it is in Incognito mode/Guest window. For example opening a Guest Window and typing "dr w" into the address bar suggests the following searches:

- dr w - Google Search
- dr w**ho**
- dr w**ho actors**

Why/how is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Since Chrome 76 there is an experimental offline prediction model that allows it to create search suggestions locally. In Chrome 87 if I go to chrome://flags/ and search for "incognito" the following experiment is found:

> **Omnibox on device head suggestions (incognito only)**
>
> Google head non personalized search suggestions provided by a compact on device model for incognito

The rationale is that [the model reduces the time it takes for suggestions to appear](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=925072) (which is useful in poor network environments). Predictions that come from the local model [don't appear to send anything over the network](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/89.0.4367.1/components/omnibox/browser/on_device_head_provider.cc) which would explain why it can be used in incognito-style environments (as predictions are not leaking the partial searches). It's not 100% clear but it looks like the model may actually be shipped within Chrome itself but it can also be [downloaded and updated](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=925072#c16).